# Could not load panel in rviz -- PluginlibFactory: The plugin for class

Tags: ros, rviz, librviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I have heavy problems with developing own panel i rviz. I have prepared everything, it compiles without warning but while loading, the rviz writes

> PluginlibFactory: The plugin for class
> 'assistant_panel/Widget_interface'
> failed to load.  Error: Failed to load
> library
> /home/xxx/ws/ws_linux/devel/lib/libassistant_panel.so.
> Make sure that you are calling the
> PLUGINLIB_EXPORT_CLASS macro in the
> library code, and that names are
> consistent between this macro and your
> XML. Error string: Could not load
> library (Poco exception =
> /home/xxx/ws/ws_linux/devel/lib/libassistant_panel.so:
> undefined symbol:
> _ZTVN15assistant_panel16Widget_interfaceE)

Eveyrthing looks ok, but I am trying to solve it for last two days but I am failing.

link for the soft: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5_3aKfZ-sqNVHpQQ3o3YkV0S0k/view?usp=sharing

Files:

CMakeLists.txt

```
##############################################################################
# CMake
##############################################################################

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.0)
project(assistant_panel)

##############################################################################
# Catkin
##############################################################################

# qt_build provides the qt cmake glue, roscpp the comms for a default talker
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS qt_build roscpp rviz)
include_directories(${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS})
# Use this to define what the package will export (e.g. libs, headers).
# Since the default here is to produce only a binary, we don't worry about
# exporting anything. 
catkin_package()

##############################################################################
# Qt Environment
##############################################################################

# this comes from qt_build's qt-ros.cmake which is automatically 
# included via the dependency call in package.xml
rosbuild_prepare_qt4(QtCore QtGui) # Add the appropriate components to the component list here

##############################################################################
# Sections
##############################################################################

file(GLOB QT_FORMS RELATIVE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} ui/*.ui)
file(GLOB QT_RESOURCES RELATIVE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} resources/*.qrc)
file(GLOB_RECURSE QT_MOC RELATIVE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} FOLLOW_SYMLINKS include/assistant_panel/*.hpp)

QT4_ADD_RESOURCES(QT_RESOURCES_CPP ${QT_RESOURCES})
QT4_WRAP_UI(QT_FORMS_HPP ${QT_FORMS})
QT4_WRAP_CPP(QT_MOC_HPP ${QT_MOC})

##############################################################################
# Sources
##############################################################################

file(GLOB_RECURSE QT_SOURCES RELATIVE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} FOLLOW_SYMLINKS src/*.cpp)

##############################################################################
# Binaries
##############################################################################

#add_executable(assistant_panel ${QT_SOURCES} ${QT_RESOURCES_CPP} ${QT_FORMS_HPP} ${QT_MOC_HPP}  ${QT_MOC})

add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} ${QT_SOURCES} ${QT_RESOURCES_CPP} ${QT_MOC})


target_link_libraries(assistant_panel ${QT_LIBRARIES} ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
#install(TARGETS assistant_panel RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_BIN_DESTINATION})

install(TARGETS
  ${PROJECT_NAME}
  ARCHIVE DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_LIB_DESTINATION}
  LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_LIB_DESTINATION}
  RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_BIN_DESTINATION}
)

install(FILES 
  plugin_description.xml
  DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_SHARE_DESTINATION})

install(DIRECTORY media/
  DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_SHARE_DESTINATION}/media)

install(DIRECTORY icons/
  DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_SHARE_DESTINATION}/icons)

install(PROGRAMS scripts/send_test_msgs.py
  DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_BIN_DESTINATION})
```

Package.xml

```
<package>
  <name>assistant_panel</name>
  <version>0.1.0</version>
  <description>

     assistant_panel

  </description>
  <maintainer email="ReMeDi@gmail.com">ReMeDi</maintainer>
  <author>ReMeDi</author>
  <license>BSD</license>
  <!-- <url type="bugtracker">https://github.com/stonier/qt_ros/issues</url> -->
  <!-- <url type="repository">https://github.com/stonier/qt_ros</url> -->


  <buildtool_depend>catkin</buildtool_depend>
  <build_depend>qt_build</build_depend>
  <build_depend>roscpp</build_depend>
  <build_depend>libqt4-dev</build_depend>
  <build_depend>rviz</build_depend>

  <run_depend>rviz</run_depend>
  <run_depend>qt_build</run_depend>
  <run_depend>roscpp</run_depend>
  <run_depend>libqt4-dev</run_depend>
  
  
  <export>
      <rosdoc config="${prefix}/rosdoc.yaml"/>
      <rviz plugin="${prefix}/plugin_description.xml"/>
  </export>
 
</package>
```

plugin_description.xml

```
<library path="libassistant_panel">
  <class name="assistant_panel/Widget_interface"
         type="assistant_panel::Widget_interface"
         base_class_type="rviz::Panel">
    <description>
      sddfsrfrfvg.
    </description>
  </class>
</library>
```

main_window.hpp

```
   /**
 * @file /include/assistant_panel/main_window.hpp
 *
 * @brief Qt based gui for assistant_panel.
 *
 * @date November 2010
 **/
#ifndef assistant_panel_MAIN_WINDOW_H
#define assistant_panel_MAIN_WINDOW_H

/*****************************************************************************
** Includes
*****************************************************************************/

//#include <QtGui/QWidget_interface>
#include "ui_main_window.h"
#include "qnode.hpp"
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <geometry_msgs/Twist.h>
#include <rviz/panel.h>

/*****************************************************************************
** Namespace
*****************************************************************************/

namespace assistant_panel {

/*****************************************************************************
** Interface [Widget_interface]
*****************************************************************************/
/**
 * @brief Qt central, all operations relating to the view part here.
 */
class Widget_interface : public rviz::Panel {
Q_OBJECT

public:
   // Widget_interface();
    Widget_interface(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~Widget_interface();

public Q_SLOTS:
    /******************************************
    ** Auto-connections (connectSlotsByName())
    *******************************************/

    /******************************************
    ** Manual connections
    *******************************************/

private:
    Ui::Widget_interface ui;
    //QNode qnode;
};

}  // namespace assistant_panel

#endif // assistant_panel_MAIN_WINDOW_H
```

main_window.cpp

```
/**
 * @file /src/main_window.cpp
 *
 * @brief Implementation for the qt gui.
 *
 * @date February 2011
 **/
/*****************************************************************************
** Includes
*****************************************************************************/

#include <QtGui>
#include <QMessageBox>
#include <iostream>
#include "../include/assistant_panel/main_window.hpp"

/*****************************************************************************
** Namespaces
*****************************************************************************/

namespace assistant_panel {

//using namespace Qt;

/*****************************************************************************
** Implementation [Widget_interface]
*****************************************************************************/

Widget_interface::Widget_interface(QWidget *parent)
    : rviz::Panel(parent)

{
    ui.setupUi(this); // Calling this incidentally connects all ui's triggers to on_...() callbacks in this class.

    setWindowIcon(QIcon(":/images/icon.png"));

}
}  // namespace assistant_panel

#include <pluginlib/class_list_macros.h>

PLUGINLIB_EXPORT_CLASS(assistant_panel::Widget_interface, rviz::Panel)
```

CMakeLists.txt

```
##############################################################################
# CMake
###################################################################

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.0)
project(assistant_panel)

##############################################################################
# Catkin
##############################################################################

# qt_build provides the qt cmake glue, roscpp the comms for a default talker
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS qt_build roscpp rviz)
include_directories(${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS})
# Use this to define what the package will export (e.g. libs, headers).
# Since the default here is to produce only a binary, we don't worry about
# exporting anything. 
catkin_package()

##############################################################################
# Qt Environment
##############################################################################

# this comes from qt_build's qt-ros.cmake which is automatically 
# included via the dependency call in package.xml
rosbuild_prepare_qt4(QtCore QtGui) # Add the appropriate components to the component list here

##############################################################################
# Sections
##############################################################################

file(GLOB QT_FORMS RELATIVE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} ui/*.ui)
file(GLOB QT_RESOURCES RELATIVE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} resources/*.qrc)
file(GLOB_RECURSE QT_MOC RELATIVE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} FOLLOW_SYMLINKS include/assistant_panel/*.hpp)

QT4_ADD_RESOURCES(QT_RESOURCES_CPP ${QT_RESOURCES})
QT4_WRAP_UI(QT_FORMS_HPP ${QT_FORMS})
QT4_WRAP_CPP(QT_MOC_HPP ${QT_MOC})

##############################################################################
# Sources
##############################################################################

file(GLOB_RECURSE QT_SOURCES RELATIVE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} FOLLOW_SYMLINKS src/*.cpp)

##############################################################################
# Binaries
##############################################################################

#add_executable(assistant_panel ${QT_SOURCES} ${QT_RESOURCES_CPP} ${QT_FORMS_HPP} ${QT_MOC_HPP}  ${QT_MOC})

add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} ${QT_SOURCES} ${QT_RESOURCES_CPP} ${QT_MOC})


target_link_libraries(assistant_panel ${QT_LIBRARIES} ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
#install(TARGETS assistant_panel RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_BIN_DESTINATION})

install(TARGETS
  ${PROJECT_NAME}
  ARCHIVE DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_LIB_DESTINATION}
  LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_LIB_DESTINATION}
  RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_BIN_DESTINATION}
)

install(FILES 
  plugin_description.xml
  DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_SHARE_DESTINATION})

install(DIRECTORY media/
  DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_SHARE_DESTINATION}/media)

install(DIRECTORY icons/
  DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_SHARE_DESTINATION}/icons)

install(PROGRAMS scripts/send_test_msgs.py
  DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_BIN_DESTINATION})
```

Package.xml

```
<package>
  <name>assistant_panel</name>
  <version>0.1.0</version>
  <description>

     assistant_panel

  </description>
  <maintainer email="ReMeDi@gmail.com">ReMeDi</maintainer>
  <author>ReMeDi</author>
  <license>BSD</license>
  <!-- <url type="bugtracker">https://github.com/stonier/qt_ros/issues</url> -->
  <!-- <url type="repository">https://github.com/stonier/qt_ros</url> -->


  <buildtool_depend>catkin</buildtool_depend>
  <build_depend>qt_build</build_depend>
  <build_depend>roscpp</build_depend>
  <build_depend>libqt4-dev</build_depend>
  <build_depend>rviz</build_depend>

  <run_depend>rviz</run_depend>
  <run_depend>qt_build</run_depend>
  <run_depend>roscpp</run_depend>
  <run_depend>libqt4-dev</run_depend>
  
  
  <export>
      <rosdoc config="${prefix}/rosdoc.yaml"/>
      <rviz plugin="${prefix}/plugin_description.xml"/>
  </export>
 
</package>
```

plugin_description.xml

```
<library path="libassistant_panel">
  <class name="assistant_panel/Widget_interface"
         type="assistant_panel::Widget_interface"
         base_class_type="rviz::Panel">
    <description>
      sddfsrfrfvg.
    </description>
  </class>
</library>
```

main_window.hpp

```
   /**
 * @file /include/assistant_panel/main_window.hpp
 *
 * @brief Qt based gui for assistant_panel.
 *
 * @date November 2010
 **/
#ifndef assistant_panel_MAIN_WINDOW_H
#define assistant_panel_MAIN_WINDOW_H

/*****************************************************************************
** Includes
*****************************************************************************/

//#include <QtGui/QWidget_interface>
#include "ui_main_window.h"
#include "qnode.hpp"
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <geometry_msgs/Twist.h>
#include <rviz/panel.h>

/*****************************************************************************
** Namespace
*****************************************************************************/

namespace assistant_panel {

/*****************************************************************************
** Interface [Widget_interface]
*****************************************************************************/
/**
 * @brief Qt central, all operations relating to the view part here.
 */
class Widget_interface : public rviz::Panel {
Q_OBJECT

public:
   // Widget_interface();
    Widget_interface(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~Widget_interface();

public Q_SLOTS:
    /******************************************
    ** Auto-connections (connectSlotsByName())
    *******************************************/

    /******************************************
    ** Manual connections
    *******************************************/

private:
    Ui::Widget_interface ui;
    //QNode qnode;
};

}  // namespace assistant_panel

#endif // assistant_panel_MAIN_WINDOW_H
```

main_window.cpp

```
/**
 * @file /src/main_window.cpp
 *
 * @brief Implementation for the qt gui.
 *
 * @date February 2011
 **/
/*****************************************************************************
** Includes
*****************************************************************************/

#include <QtGui>
#include <QMessageBox>
#include <iostream>
#include "../include/assistant_panel/main_window.hpp"

/*****************************************************************************
** Namespaces
*****************************************************************************/

namespace assistant_panel {

//using namespace Qt;

/*****************************************************************************
** Implementation [Widget_interface]
*****************************************************************************/

Widget_interface::Widget_interface(QWidget *parent)
    : rviz::Panel(parent)

{
    ui.setupUi(this); // Calling this incidentally connects all ui's triggers to on_...() callbacks in this class.

    setWindowIcon(QIcon(":/images/icon.png"));

}
}  // namespace assistant_panel

#include <pluginlib/class_list_macros.h>

PLUGINLIB_EXPORT_CLASS(assistant_panel::Widget_interface, rviz::Panel)
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/215487/could-not-load-panel-in-rviz----pluginlibfactory:-the-plugin-for-class-.../) by [mcholewi](https://answers.ros.org/users/22011/mcholewi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2015-08-09

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2015-08-10**:
This usually happens when you're loading a version of the plugin from a different, overlayed workspace. Make sure you've source'd any setup.bash from your latest workspace before running rviz.

**Comment by [mcholewi](https://answers.ros.org/users/22011/mcholewi/) on 2015-08-12**:
Yes, I am loading. As I have written below the rviz want the symbol, which is actually Undefined. Well, it is very strange, because I have panel which works perfectly. The only difference is not using the ui_ generated header and slightly different CMakeLists. I`ve checked that it is no CMakLists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I encountered similar question when **using pluginlib for loading my customized rviz panel**, but I was using **CMAKE_AUTOMOC** for my qt objects. (Working on Ubuntu 14.04, ROS indigo)

My file system structure is like this:

```
pkg_folder
\-  config
\-  include/rviz_panel.h
\-  src/rviz_panel.cpp
\-  CMakeLists.txt
\-  package.xml
\-  package_description.xml
```

The core parts for add_library is:

```
catkin_package()
include_directories(include)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(HEADER_FILES
   include/FrameFabRvizPanel.h
)
set(SRC_FILES
    src/FrameFabRvizPanel.cpp
    #src/FrameFab.cpp
    #src/FrameFabRenderWidget.cpp
    #src/WireFrame.cpp
    )
**add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SRC_FILES})**
target_link_libraries(
    ${PROJECT_NAME} ${QT_LIBRARIES} ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
)
```

Using this cmake file and package xml and description xml following official [rviz plugin tutorial](https://github.com/ros-visualization/visualization_tutorials/tree/kinetic-devel/rviz_plugin_tutorials), I went through catkin_make process smoothly and harvest my lib_pkg.so successfully.

Then launching process for Rviz went on smoothly, and I can even see my panel in the add_new_panel list.

But when I click on it to open it, ROS pumped out an ERROR:

```
PluginlibFactory: The plugin for class 'framefab_mpp/FrameFabRvizPanel' failed to load.  Error: Failed to load library /home/yijiangh/catkin_ws/devel/lib//libframefab_mpp.so. Make sure that you are calling the PLUGINLIB_EXPORT_CLASS macro in the library code, and that names are consistent between this macro and your XML. Error string: Could not load library (Poco exception = /home/yijiangh/catkin_ws/devel/lib//libframefab_mpp.so: undefined symbol: _ZTVN8framefab17FrameFabRvizPanelE)
```

(Exactly the same symptom @mcholewi has encountered in [his thread](http://answers.ros.org/question/215487/could-not-load-panel-in-rviz-pluginlibfactory-the-plugin-for-class/?answer=215543#post-id-215543))

When using `rospack plugins --attrib=plugin rviz`, I can successfully see the `plugin_description.xml` address for my pkg.

After getting stuck for 3 days, I happened to see [this thread in stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37151163/cmake-automoc-with-files-on-different-folders). And it just saved huge amount of my time!

So change my CMakeLists.txt file like this:

change this line:

```
**add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SRC_FILES})**
```

into

```
**add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SRC_FILES} ${HEADER_FILES})**
```

*And everything just works like a charm.*

I think the reason can be found at CMake AUTOMOC official doc:

> If an #include statement like #include "moc_foo.cpp" is found, **the Q_OBJECT class declaration is expected in the header**, and moc is run on the header file. A moc_foo.cpp file will be generated from the source’s header into the CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR directory. This allows the compiler to find the included moc_foo.cpp file regardless of the location the original source. **However, if multiple source files in different directories do this then their generated moc files would collide. In this case a diagnostic will be issued.**

So in my previous mistake, the QObject declaration cannot be found thus pluginlib found my customized panel (FrameFabRvizPanel in my case) is undefined.

Thus the solution would be:

- You can put cpp and header files for your rviz related plugin together in one folder
- or use the technique stated above (link both source and header to your created library)

---

Originally posted by [yijiangh](https://answers.ros.org/users/28469/yijiangh/) with karma: 131 on 2017-04-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 9

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [clyde](https://answers.ros.org/users/28405/clyde/) on 2017-11-19**:
This solved my problem as well! My directory structure is slightly different. I replaced this line:

```
add_library(orca_topside src/orca_panel.cpp)
```

with this line:

```
add_library(orca_topside src/orca_panel.cpp include/orca_topside/orca_panel.h)
```

And it worked!

**Comment by [martin1412](https://answers.ros.org/users/25296/martin1412/) on 2018-05-11**:
Thank you, solved it for me as well